# How do I make my program print all data typed by user after "exit" is typed

Tags: c++

This is an assignment that I have been given:

> Write a program that repeatedly asks the user to type in a sentence and press Enter. Your program will store each sentence the user types into some container. When the user types "exit" or "Exit", print every sentence back to the screen in alphabetical order and then exit.

Below is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    string data;
    vector data;
    do
    {
        cout << "Type a sentence and press enter."
            "If the word 'exit' is typed, the program will close." << endl;

        getline(cin, data);

        // validate if data is not equals to "exit"
        if (data != "exit" && data != "Exit" )
        {
            // then type back
            cout << data << endl;
        }
    }
    while (data != "exit" && data != "Exit");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ever thought of using the `qsort` function? Or you can use what @paddy has suggested, `std::sort`.

Comment: I have never heard of that. My professor had advised us to do it this way with a vector container.

Comment: `vector data;` ?? --> `vector<string> datav;`,  `{while` --> `}while`

Comment: Use `std::sort`.  `qsort` hails from the C era and is less efficient due to C's lack of templating.

Comment: you have 2 variables with the same name. Not allowed. Start out ignoring the sort requirement, just read lines into the vector until the user types exit. Build it up bit by bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow the directions you were given:

> Write a program that repeatedly asks the user to type in a sentence and press Enter. **Your program will store each sentence the user types into some container**. When the user types "exit" or "Exit", print every sentence back to the screen in alphabetical order and then exit.

You are not storing the sentences anywhere, so you can't sort them.  You need to do something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    string line;
    vector<string> data;

    do
    {
        cout << "Type a sentence and press enter." << endl;
        cout << "If the word 'exit' is typed, the program will close." << endl;

        if (!getline(cin, line))
            break;

        // validate if data is equal to "exit"
        if ((line == "exit") || (line == "Exit"))
            break;

        data.push_back(line); // <-- ADD THIS!!
    }
    while (true);

    // sort the data alphabetically
    sort(data.begin(), data.end()); // <-- ADD THIS!!

    // then type it back out
    for(vector<string>::iterator i = data.begin(); i != data.end(); ++i) {
        cout << *i << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: make sure you give Remy full credit when you submit this solution

Comment: Thank-you a ton Remy!! I have struggled a ton in this class. Also could you explain the "data.push_back(line)"? I appreciate every ones input and I will credit Remy in my assignment

Comment: Look up std::vector in your book/c++ reference; it should explain the push_back member function.

Comment: @GarrettRichards it appends the string called line (which is the input coming from the console) to a vector of strings. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/

Comment: Thank you guys. Y'all are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

When looking for some type of sorting function, I recommend using `std:sort()`, because it was created for `C++`. You can use `qsort()`, but don't due to it's on `C`.

What the `std:sort()` function does is sorts a range of elements in ascending order, which is what you want. The header to use when using this function is `#include <algorithm>`. For more information about this function, [check this link out](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).